# Generating a has_one association for an existing model correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm experiencing some issues when trying to add a has_one relation to existing model. I ran
`rails g migration AddPracticeToLesson practice:references`
and generated the following migration

```rb
class AddPracticeToLesson < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_reference :lessons, :practice, null: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

and I have the lesson model as

```rb
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  acts_as_list

  belongs_to :course

  has_many :sections, -> { order(position: :asc) }, as: :sectionable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :quiz, through: :sections
  has_one :practice # ADDED THIS
  has_one_attached :cover_image
end
```

to which I added the line `has_one :practice`. I also added `belongs_to :lesson, optional: true` for the practice model which now looks like

```rb
class Practice < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  enum status: [:unpublished, :published]

  has_many :sections, -> { order(position: :asc) }, as: :sectionable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :quiz, through: :sections
  has_one_attached :cover_image

  belongs_to :lesson, optional: true
end
```

but now upon running `@lesson.practice` will result in an error stating

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column practices.lesson_id does not exist
```

which I don't understand. Why is it trying to access practices.lesson_id and not just find the practice with the lesson.practice_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you have defined the reference on the wrong table.

From https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association:

> A has_one association indicates that one other model has a reference to this model. That model can be fetched through this association.

What this means in practice is that your table `practice` (or `practices` whichever is the real table name) should have a reference to `lessons`.

In your migration, change

```
add_reference :lessons, :practice, null: true, foreign_key: true
```

to

```
add_reference :practice, :lessons, null: true, foreign_key: true
```

---

If you want to use the Rails generators,

```
rails g migration AddLessonRefToPractices lesson:references
```

seemed to create the correct migration

```
class AddLessonRefToPractices < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_reference :practices, :lesson, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

I took the naming convention for the migration from https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration (scroll down to where they define the *AddUserRefToProducts* migration, almost until section 2.2).

Naming the migration matters, at least in some cases, as Rails tries to conclude from the name and given attributes what you want to do.

Put another way, whenever you use the association `belongs_to` the reference field must always be defined in that table (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association). As your `Practice` model defines `belongs_to :lesson`, the reference field must be defined in the table for `Practice`.

Comment: Thank you Jarno for the answer! I'm wondering what would be the correct migration to run then using the rails generator? I thought that `rails g migration AddPracticeToLesson practice:references` or `rails g migration AddPracticeToLesson practice:belongs_to` would be the correct ones (they produce same results), but seems that it's not the case then here? @jarno-lamberg

Comment: Most often, I just give a migration name on the command line and then manually write the contents of it unless I am adding some simple fields. That way, I get it done right. 
Using `references` and `belongs_to` in migrations should give the same result: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_belongs_to. 
Btw, if my answer helped, maybe you can mark it as the accepted answer? :)

Comment: I updated the answer with a bit more information and the command to create the correct migration.